# Bundle Install hanging when installing anything that needs to compile C code (MacOS Ventura)

Tags: ruby, rubygems, macos-ventura

I updated my machine (MacBook Pro, Intel Core) to Ventura and have not been able to run `bundle install` on a fresh repo since. The install seems to get hung up on gems that need to compile C code (e.g. msgpack).

I am running this within a docker container. I am on the latest version of docker.

There are no errors, the bundle command just hangs on the line `Installing msgpack 1.6.0 with native extensions`.

While debugging another issue running a server, I was able to run bundle install, but in an attempt to address that other issue, I deleted the `.bundle` directory and was attempting to reinstall the gems from scratch. This is when I ran into the above mentioned issue.

Expected that running `bundle install` would successfully install all of the specified gems in the Gemfile.

Edit:
Ruby version 2.7.4

Comment: Just added, apologies for not including earlier. Ruby version is 2.7.4

Answer (score 1):

Found out the issue was around nfs chunk sizing. Solution was to edit the `docker/compose-files/volumes.docker-sync.yml` file to add `wsize=65536,rsize=65536` to the options.